# Render data from database in layout file

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to include data (fetching from a database) in the _layout file of my asp.net mvc core project.

Situation:

**_Layout page**

```
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
   Html.Action("Modules", "Layout")
}
```

**Controllers/LayoutController.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace project.Controllers
{
   public class LayoutController : Controller
   {
       ...

       public ActionResult Modules()
       {
           ///Return all the modules
           return PartialView("_Modules", moduleAccess.ToList());
       }
   }
}
```

**Views/Shared/_Modules.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<project.Models.Module>
<div class="two wide column">
<div class="ui menu" id="modules">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <a class="item">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </a>
    }
</div>
```

When going the webpage I get the following error:

```
'IHtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'Action' and the best extension method overload 'UrlHelperExtensions.Action(IUrlHelper, string, object)' requires a receiver of type 'IUrlHelper'
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the data in the layout page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core instead of Html.Action use [View Components](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/view-components.html): `@await Component.InvoceAsync`.

You can still use `@await Html.RenderPariantAsync` and pass there some data from the model if you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution with view components**

***ViewComponents/ModuleListViewComponent.cs***

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ViewComponents
{
   public class ModuleListViewComponent : ViewComponent
   {
       ...

       public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
       {
           return View(moduleAccess.ToList());
       }     
   }
}
```

***Views/Shared/Components/ModuleList/Default.cshtml***

```
@model IEnumerable<project.Models.AdminModels.Module>

<div class="two wide column">
<div class="ui left vertical labeled icon menu stackable" id="modules">
    @foreach (var module in Model)
    {
        <a class="item">
            @module.Name
        </a>
    }
</div>
</div>
```

***Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml***

```
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("ModuleList")
}
```